# Getting data from external server with JSONP

Tags: ajax, json, get, jsonp, external

Im trying to get some data from a web api on an external server. I can see the right data under Network -> Response in Chrome debugger.

If i replace my url with a flicker JSON url i get a success. I can see in the Response that the data is show differently, but i dont know how to change my data to the same as flickr.

I made a Fiddle to demonstrate my problem: [jsfiddle/8JDna/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/8JDna/2/)

```
<body>
    <div id="content">

        <div class="well">

        </div>        
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

$(function () {

    var thisMonth = 0;

    var flickrURL = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?';
    var myURL = 'http://driving.thylle.dk/api/distance?jsoncallback=?';

    $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            format: "json"
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $(".well").html("<h3> SUCCESS </h3>");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            $(".well" ).html("Error: " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);

        },
    });
});
```

I hope you can understand my question

Best regards Rasmus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server under your second URL doesn't actually return a JSONP response, but just plain JSON. If you have control over that server, you have to use the `jsoncallback` parameter in order to wrap the JSON like this:

```
// jsoncallback=cb
cb( ["you JSON response in here"] );
```

So in PHP, e.g., currently you might have something like this:

```
echo json_encode( $result );
```

You should change this to

```
echo $_REQUEST['jsoncallback'], "(", json_encode( $result ), ");";
```

Comment: Thank you @Sirko, i was figureing that it had something to do with my api code. Yes i have access, but im using C# so currently i have this.

`public IEnumerable<Driving_distance> GetDriving_distance()
{
     return db.Driving_distance.AsEnumerable();
}`

Comment: @Thylle I'm not that familiar with C#, but just output the parameter you get by `jsoncallback` followed by `(`, you actual content and `);`.

Comment: Thanks @Sirko, i am able to get the data now, thanks to you. You made me look elsewhere. Now the problem is that i cant post to the server.

I get a success message, but the data hasent been pushed?

Comment: @Thylle I suggest opening a new question for that problem. It may be related to the [Same Origin Policy](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-Origin-Policy).